# ¿Es normal que en tiempo de ejecucion Android no realize consultas a db?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

no se como manejar mi problema, tengo mi aplicación, es bastante grande y tiene mucho código, realiza todo perfectamente pero tengo un problema en tiempo de ejecución, tengo unos `checkbox`´s los cuales cuando se marcan realizan una modificación en la base de datos interna de la aplicación, y cuando se desmarcan realizan el mismo proceso, una modificación a la base de datos, los 2 modifican el valor que esta asignado como mostrar en la aplicación dicho elemento en un `gridview`, cuando se marca se muestra y cuando se desmarca se oculta.

El problema viene cuando marco o desmarco los `checkbox`: 
hay veces que realiza la modificación en la base de datos y otras veces no, de ahí mi pregunta, si es normal que en tiempo de ejecución aleatoriamente haga las modificaciones en la base de datos y si hay alguna manera de controlar esto para que siempre lo realice. Dejo algo de código para que se entienda.

Metodos de modificacion de la base de datos:

```
public int updateShowMain1(String articulo){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("showMain", 1);
    Log.i("","Recibe la consulta");
    return db.update("articles",valores,"description = ?", new String[]{articulo});

    //return db.execSQL("UPDATE articles SET showMain = 1 WHERE description = articulo");

}

public int updateShowMain0(String articulo){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("showMain", 0);

    return db.update("articles",valores,"description = ?", new String[]{articulo});

    //return db.execSQL("UPDATE articles SET showMain = 1 WHERE description = articulo");

}
```

Código Checkbox:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
                Utility.dbHelper.updateShowMain1(articulo.getText().toString());
                Log.i("","Ejecuta la consulta");
                Log.i("","articulo"+ articulo.getText().toString());
            }
            if (!checkBox.isChecked()){
                Utility.dbHelper.updateShowMain0(articulo.getText().toString());
                Log.i("","Ejecuta la consulta");
                Log.i("","articulo"+ articulo.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Un saludo

Comment: Tal y como veo... has probado a hacer las modificaciones con un AsyncTask? puede ser que en el tiempo de ejjecucion de la aplicacion se te haga todo un lio y por eso no vaya bien.

Comment: Te sugiero encarecidamente que leas como usar los ContentProvider, te permite manejar la base de datos muy facilmente y detectar cualquier cambio permitiendo asi actualizar la vista y la bd en tiempo real. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating?hl=es-419

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, creo que voy a tirar por Asynctask para hacer las consultas en segundo plano, pero lo que no se es como hacer para pasarle un parametro de otro lado al asynctask, he provado declarandolo en parameters pero no funciona

Comment: @J.Burrueco En este caso usar o no Asynctask no es estrictamente necesario. Solo necesitas actualizar el valor showMain contenido en  ContentValues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que no existe problema al llamar [getReadableDatabase()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()), método el cual permite crear o abrir una base de datos.

En realidad me parece que el problema es el contenido del texto dentro del `EditText`, ya que los métodos que usas usan este texto para determinar actualizar un registro en base a su descripción.

Por lo tanto para que se realice la actualización de los datos, el campo descripción debe ser igual a :

```
articulo.getText().toString()
```

Las posibles razones por las cuales no sucedería actualización de los datos que :

> - La descripción no existiera en tu tabla.
> - La descripción existe pero el texto contenido dentro de articulo.getText().toString() tiene algún espacio.

Si el texto tiene algún espacio, NO se realizará la actualización de los datos, para esto te sugiero usar el método [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--)

```
articulo.getText().toString().trim()
```

de esta forma eliminarías los espacios en blanco contenidos dentro del `EditText`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, he usado lo que me has comentado, usar el método .trim() pero me da el mismo resultado, a veces realiza la modificación en la base de datos y otras veces no, es aleatorio, por eso creo que se debe a la sobrecarga del hilo principal y que debo realizar estas modificaciones en segundo plano o en un hilo secundario, buscare información porque no tengo mun ejemplo claro de como hacerlo, un saludo.

Comment: He cambiado el diseño de el listview y en vez de realizar la modificacion con el checkbox lo he echo con unos botones y todo perfecto, un saludo